# How to create a new storage pool with virt-manager?

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

In virt-manager I see that my default storage pool is almost full.

When I create a new storage pool, it doesn't help, because it has the same usage percentage as the default.

As you see, I don't understand it. What must I do?

Thanks,

Eric J.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Fedora's documentation for creating a new storage pool. It's pretty straightforward and simple.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-partbased-storage-pool.html